# Virtuemart which variable holds order_number value of cart?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, virtuemart

Can anyone please tell me which variable holds virtuemart cart order_number value? I want to get it before checkout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can probably locate which variable holds this nunber by using the following output:

```
print_r(get_defined_vars()); // prints all declared variables
print_r($this); // prints the current object
```

Try these, and see if you can find your variable :)